# Is "in the case" the same as "with"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, difference

I started using ProWritingAid - writing checker. When I am writing "in the case", this software suggests that "Readability can be enhanced by using with". This checker shows I should always use "with" in the place of "in the case" to have better readability. According to ProWritingAid, there is no difference between "in the case" and "with". Is this true?

For example:

In the case of Italians, pizza is more popular that cake.

ProWritingAid wants to change the above sentence into the following sentence:

With Italians, pizza is more popular that cake.

Comment: Can you give us an example in a sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both sentences, "that" should be "than." Other than that, the two sentences are equivalent in meaning in this case.

I recently watched a video in which an English teacher suggests that it is a bad idea to let computers make stylistic choices and that the shortest option is not automatically the best. In this particular case, my opinion is that this change does not affect the style or tone, but you still may be interested to see the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5rB9jDbTPU

Comment: Thank you. I also thought the "that" was incorrect, but I took that sentence from a site that was supposed to teach English and it confused me: https://englishstudypage.com/grammar/in-case-of-vs-in-the-case-of-in-english/

Comment: The sentence on the website is wrong.